# Ansible create sha512-pbkdf2 hash

Tags: hash, ansible, pbkdf2

The mosquitto_passwd (https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_passwd-1.html) command creates a hash password based on sha512-pbkdf2 (default).

Is there a way to create a sha512-pbkdf2 hash from e.g. a variable in Ansible?

Answer (score 3):

I created a custom filter for this.
Create a directory `filter_plugins` adjacent to your playbook, then create a file `filters.py` in there:

```py
# Custom filters for use with ansible
def mosquitto_passwd(passwd):
    from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
    from base64 import b64encode
    import secrets

    # See https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/src/password_mosq.h
    iterations = 101

    salt = secrets.token_bytes(12)
    dk = pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',
                     bytes(passwd, 'utf-8'),
                     salt,
                     iterations
                     )
    return (
            "$7$" + str(iterations) + "$" +
            b64encode(salt).decode() + "$" +
            b64encode(dk).decode()
            )

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'mosquitto_passwd': mosquitto_passwd,
        }
```

Then you can generate mosquitto hashes with `{{ password | mosquitto_passwd }}`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use `passlib` which is now the recommended pip package for password hash generation in Ansible.

Building on Dick Visser's answer:

### Code

#### `filter_plugins/mosquitto_passwd.py`

```py
from ansible.errors import AnsibleError


def mosquitto_passwd(passwd):
    try:
        import passlib.hash
    except Exception as e:
        raise AnsibleError('to use this filter, you need passlib pip package installed')
    SALT_SIZE = 12
    ITERATIONS = 101
    
    digest = passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha512.using(salt_size=SALT_SIZE, rounds=ITERATIONS)\
                                        .hash(passwd) \
                                        .replace('pbkdf2-sha512', '7') \
                                        .replace('.', '+')

    return digest + '=='


class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'mosquitto_passwd': mosquitto_passwd,
        }
```

The filter will also replace the default text generated of `$pbkdf2-sha512$` to `$7$` and replace any `.` which is `passlib`'s way of compacting Base64 encode with `+` to make it a valid hash for Mosquitto Broker